# Plotting neural networks

Tags: windows, graphs, neural-network, plotting

I am looking for a Windows program that I can use to plot neural networks in a convenient way (i.e. I know I can do it on MS Paint but looking for an efficient tool). Ideally the output should be vectorial.

Example 1:

[image]

Example 2

[image]

Comment: Franck, your question is well written for what you seek.  What you seek, however, will limit the design of your neural networks.  One of the beauties of neural nets is unique designs with greater flexibility and feedback.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I agree, just wanted to start easy with MLP and CNN :)